# css3-mediaqueries.js not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, media-queries

css3-mediaqueries.js works in IE8 only if @media styles comes in your html inside the  tag. I waste too much time, when tried to get it work in IE8, so I hope this post will be helpful for other people.
My solution is simple: all works fine if your files only on webserver, bun not works on local machine. So if you want test css3-mediaqueries.js you need to copy all your files to your server and test it online!